# Problema usando javascript, NODE JS e base de dados CSV

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, banco-de-dados

Olá!

Estou fazendo um projeto para a escola usando o Bluemix da IBM e estou tendo alguns problemas em encontrar meu erro. Estou usando uma base de dados em CSV que tem como parâmetros o bairro, número de quartos, área em metros quadrados, preço entre outras informações de apartamentos. Eu também tenho um arquivo JADE que contém um formulário a ser preenchido pelo usuário na minha página principal. Uma vez preenchido, meu `app.js` deveria ser capaz de cruzar as informações providas pelo usuário (número de quartos que ele deseja, valor máximo que está disposto a pagar) com o a base de dados, retornando em outra página a lista de apartamentos da base de dados que se encaixam no que o usuário pediu.

Contudo, por alguma razão, isto não está acontecendo. Acredito que o erro possa estar em alguma dessas linhas:

```
  var resultado = {Bairro: [], quartos: [], area: [], valor: [], endereco: [], img: []};

  for (var i = 1; i < dados.Bairro.length; i++){

      if (dados.Bairro[i] == parametros.bairro && dados.quartos[i] == parametros.quartos && dados.area[i] >= Number(parametros.area) && dados.valor[i] <= Number(parametros.valor)){
```

Segue em anexo meu código. Muito obrigada!

```
/*eslint-env node*/

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// node.js starter application for Bluemix
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// This application uses express as its web server
// for more info, see: http://expressjs.com
var express = require('express');

// cfenv provides access to your Cloud Foundry environment
// for more info, see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cfenv
var cfenv = require('cfenv');

var fs = require('fs');

var parse = require('csv-parse');

// create a new express server
var app = express();

function seleciona_dados(dados, parametros){
    var resultado = {Bairro: [], quartos: [], area: [], valor: [], endereco: [], img: []};
        for (var i = 1; i < dados.Bairro.length; i++){
            if (dados.Bairro[i] == parametros.bairro && dados.quartos[i] == parametros.quartos && dados.area[i] >= Number(parametros.area) && dados.valor[i] <= Number(parametros.valor)){
                resultado.bairro.push(dados.bairro[i]);
                resultado.quartos.push(dados.quartos[i]);
                resultado.area.push(dados.area[i]);
                resultado.valor.push(dados.valor[i]);
                resultado.endereco.push(dados.endereco[i]);
                resultado.img.push(dados.img[i]);
            }
        }
    return resultado;
}

// serve the files out of ./public as our main files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// get the app environment from Cloud Foundry
var appEnv = cfenv.getAppEnv();

// start server on the specified port and binding host
app.listen(appEnv.port, '0.0.0.0', function() {

    // print a message when the server starts listening
  console.log("server starting on " + appEnv.url);
});
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('cadastro.jade', {  pageTitle: 'Cadastro Usuário'});
});
app.post('/resumo', function(req, res){
    // var furfles = req.body;

    var parser = parse({delimiter: ';'}, function(err, data){
        var dados = {bairro: [], quartos: [], area: [], valor: [], endereco: [], img: []};
        for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++){
            dados.bairro.push(data[i][0]);
            dados.quartos.push(data[i][1]);
            dados.area.push(Number(data[i][2]));
            dados.valor.push(Number(data[i][3]));
            dados.endereco.push(data[i][4]);
            dados.img.push(data[i][5]);
        }
        dados = seleciona_dados(dados, req.body);
        res.render('resumo.jade', {pageData:{  pageTitle: 'Resumo do Pedido do Usuário'}, formData: req.body, imoveis: dados});
    });

    fs.createReadStream(__dirname+'/static/BD.csv').pipe(parser);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Tem muita coisa que precisa ser vista aí. O ponto mais rápido a se atacar é essa variável `dados.Bairro` (maiúscula) que às vezes está sendo lida por `dados.bairro` (minúscula). O javascript é case-sensitive e faz diferença. Aliás, sugiro que escreva os métodos e as variáveis javascript conforme o padrão da própria linguagem (ou seja, apenas `dados.bairro` (minúscula).

Para resolver o problema de maneira mais definitiva, eu sugiro que você faça as seguintes mudanças:

**1. Não carregue o arquivo CSV a cada consulta feita pelo formulário.**

Carregue ele em memória na primeira vez e deixe numa variável. O Express permite que você compartilhe os dados das variáveis entre todas as requisições. Da maneira que está pode ser custoso buscar essa informação no arquivo toda vez.

**2. Crie um único objeto para cada registro da tabela**

```
        var dados = []    //opte por usar variáveis em inglês!
        for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++){
        dados.push({
            bairro: data[i][0],
            quartos: data[i][1],
            area: Number(data[i][2])
            valor: Number(data[i][3])
            endereco: data[i][4]
            img: data[i][5]
        })
```

**3. Apenas filtre os resultados**

No método `seleciona_dados` você pode construir um objeto novo como está fazendo (desde que corrija a variável `dados.Bairro` que está sendo lida como `dados.bairro` em alguns lugares).
É mais fácil usar a função *filter*. Tente algo nessa linha:

```
function selecionaDados(dados, p){
return dados.filter(function(dado){
    return (dado.bairro == p.bairro && dado.quartos == p.quartos && dado.area >= Number(p.area) && dado.valor <= Number(p.valor))
})
```

}

Neste caso, a função filter retornará um novo vetor com base no vetor `dados` contendo apenas os registros (no caso, lido como `dado`) que satisfaçam esse conjunto de condições.

Assim, além da consulta ser mais eficiente, o objeto de retorno será mais fácil de manipular no formulário.